# How to add antd datepicker with masked input

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, antd

This is what I want using antd datepicker.
https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/

```
<KeyboardTimePicker
 margin="normal"
 id="time-picker"
 label="Time picker"
 value={selectedDate}
 onChange={handleDateChange}
 KeyboardButtonProps={{
 'aria-label': 'change time',
 }}
/>
```

This is currently material-ui. Is there a way to add this same functionality using antd

Comment: are you using antd or material ui ? your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [antd-mask-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-mask-input) for similar implementation. It will do the job for you.

```
<MaskedInput 
   mask="11/1111" 
   name="expiry" 
   placeholder="mm/yyyy" 
   onChange={this._onChange}/>
```